# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS freeze after leaving power on overnight

Tags: 20.04, power-management, freeze

For the last 4 days my machine on the workplace keep freezing after I leave it on overnight (I only lock the screen, not sleep/hibernate). The power still on, fans running, num lock is freezing, screen is completely black, it just not wake up.
At the first day, I think it was because of I leave too many programs open, so I only leave Pycharm (no running task) and 5 tabs of Firefox before I go home. The next day it still happen, so I double check the power setting in Ubuntu, because I always disable sleep/hiberate, auto suspend right after I install the OS. They are still disabled.
Then I checked for updates. Finish all awaiting update, still freezed the next morning.
My machine specs: Dell Vostro-3670, i5-8400, 12GB RAM, 1TB HDD
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: This may having nothing to do with hibernation and the system may not actually be freezing.  To help isolate this, can you open up an ssh shell into this stems from another machine?  Next time the console is unresponsive see if the shell responds.  If it does, you can get a better idea what's causing this issue.  Like gnome going to sleep for example.

Comment: After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash/shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator this is the result of `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -ex`, I can't copy all of it to comment section so I have to take a screenshot, pls take a look
https://imgur.com/Dnqztsv